# OCaml equivalent to f# "%A"

Tags: ocaml

in F#, the following is a no brainer:

```
let l = [1;2;3;4]
let s = sprintf "%A" l
```

where "%A" prints a formatted version of virtually any common, even recursive data structure.

Is there something similarly easy in ocaml?

Comment: Ocaml has no runtime type information. That means that at runtime it has no idea that `l` is a list of ints. `type t = A | B | C | D | E let l2 = [B; C; D; E]` is absolutely identical in memory at runtime. Printing `l` and `l2` correctly becomes impossible for printf alone, it needs help (see answere below). Also how should type inference work with %A?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow In F#, the special requirement is that the format string is known at compile time. (meaning you cannot load the format string from a resource file etc...). After the compile, the printf call along with format string and arguments is statically type checked. See for example here: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/printf/ I simply assumed, there was something similar in place for ocaml.

Comment: No such compiler magic in ocaml. The format string is already magic enough that many people want to replace it with a functional solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something close, the `%a` specificator accepts two arguments, the first is a pretty printer for type `'a`, and the second is a value of type `'a`. The type of the printer, depends on the kind of used printf function. For example,

```
open Core_kernel.Std
open Format

printf "%a" Int63.pp Int63.one
```

Of course, this depends heavily on a good support from a library. If there is no `pp` function, provided for the type, then it is pretty useless.

Also there is a [custom_printf](https://github.com/janestreet/ppx_custom_printf) syntax extension available for both - pp and ppx. In this extension you place a module name in the place of specificator. The module must have a `to_string` function. The ppx version, requires an exclamation mark before the format string:

```
printf !"%{Int63}" Int63.one
```

There is also a dump function, available over the Internet. In particular you can find it in the [Batteries](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/blob/4f41b77c16d2311238de3a4afc0ab240d9692c5a/src/batPervasives.mliv#L64) library. It recurse over the data representation and print it in a more or less human readable representation. But this is not relate to the formatted output.

Comment: I saw the "%a" and the formatting module. But it stroke me as way too complicated to really consider for such an every-day thing. I think I use a battery included ocaml version but I am never sure where the batteries are or if I actually use them or instead use those old rusty nails which were there before and never got removed ;)

Comment: The presentation is indeed a bit complicated, but the usage is simple and extremely common. See also the [Fmt](http://erratique.ch/software/fmt) library.